# redirecting to a URL with hash using htaccess

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

How will I redirect my URL with a hah along.. Let us say I entered in the URL..

```
example.com/register
```

It should be redirected to

```
example.com/#/register
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs by default provides the  routing functionality using `$routeprovider` or `$stateProvider`. You can use these providers in your config.

```
angular.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {    
    $stateProvider
      .state('dashboard', {
        url:'/dashboard',
        abstract:true,  
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html'     
    })
      .state('dashboard.home',{
        url:'/home',
        templateUrl:'views/home.html'       
      })
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Comment: Actually I prefer using .htaccess for this, do you know any way?